# PrimeNg p-tree use a custom filter form field

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-tree

I want to be able to filter the tree on PrimeNG, but I need to use another field, instead of the default one that appears on top of the tree.

Is it possible to pass a string to the tree and use it as the filter while getting that string from another form field? I couldn't find a way to do it anywhere...